# How do I count the number of characters in a code using accumulation pattern without using len()?

Tags: python

Write code to count the number of characters in original_str using the accumulation pattern and assign the answer to a variable num_chars. Do NOT use the len function to solve the problem (if you use it while you are working on this problem, comment it out afterward!)

```
original_str = "The quick brown rhino jumped over the extremely lazy fox."
num_chars = len(original_str)
print(len(original_str))
for i in original_str:
    print(len(i))
```

The computer tells me this is correct, but it's doesn't answer the question. I must replace len with another function.

Comment: What’s the “accumulation pattern”?

Comment: You may need to elaborate on what you mean by the "accumulator pattern". Is that like a reduction? Looping while maintaining an accumulator? And what have you tried? What specifically do you need help with?

Comment: `original_str.count('') - 1`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you cannot use the [**`len()`**](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#len) function you could write a function like `num_characters` below that uses a for loop to iterate over the characters in the passed in `string` and increments and subsequently returns a variable `total` based on the total amount of characters. I think that is what you mean by an accumulator right?

```
def num_characters(string):
  total = 0
  for character in string:
    total += 1
  return total

original_string = "The quick brown rhino jumped over the extremely lazy fox."
print(f"The numbers of characters in the original string using `len` is {len(original_string)}.")
print(f"The numbers of characters in the original string using `num_characters` is {num_characters(original_string)}.")
```

**Output:**

```
The numbers of characters in the original string using `len` is 57.
The numbers of characters in the original string using `num_characters` is 57.
```

Answer (score 0):

With the accumulator pattern, you have a variable, and you add to it when something happens. You can make that "something" mean "counting a particular character".

So, write a loop that steps through each character in the string, and each time you go through that loop, add one to a variable, starting from zero.

Answer (score 0):

```
original_str = "The quick brown rhino jumped over the extremely lazy fox."

num_chars = original_str.count('') - 1

print (num_chars)
```

Answer (score 0):

```py
original_str = "The quick brown rhino jumped over the extremely lazy fox."
count = 0
for w in original_str:
    count = count + 1
num_chars = count
print(num_chars)
```

Comment: Could you be more specific about asking your questions. I have no idea what direction you want to go.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply. [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/25775549)

Comment: Is this not the same solution as many of the existing answers?

Answer (score 0):

original_str = "The quick brown rhino jumped over the extremely lazy fox."

```
for num_chars in range(0,58): 
print(original_str.count)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could write a loop that goes through each character in the string, and each time you go through that loop, add one to the accumulator variable. For this, you need to set the accumulator variable to zero before executing the loop.

```py
original_str = "The quick brown rhino jumped over the extremely lazy fox."

num_chars = 0
for achar in original_str:
    num_chars = num_chars + 1

print (num_chars)
```

Answer (score -1):

```
original_str = "The quick brown rhino jumped over the extremely lazy fox."

num_chars=0
for i in original_str:
    if i!=" ":
        num_chars+=1
print(num_chars)
```

Comment: Is this not the same solution as many of the existing answers?

Comment: Hope It will solve issue but please add explanation of your code with it so user will get perfect understanding which he/she really wants.